# sql show number of duplicate records

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have a table with fields recordid (unique), createdate, aID, bID , cID

There are also three definition tables for the values stored in fields aID, bID, cID

I would like to generate a resultset that shows all fields from the table, plus one more column showing the number of times duplicate records with the same aID, bID and cID were created in the last 10 minutes.

Note: the result set needs to include definitions to aID, bID and  cID using inner joins the three definition tables, for example

recordid, createdate, aID, aIDdefinition, bID, bIDdefinition, cID, cIDdefinition, [number of additional records created in last 10 minutes with same aID,bID and cID]

Finally, the select query needs to bring only the top X records, but the search for duplicates needs to be in all of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "last 10 minutes", I assume you mean relative to the current date/time rather than relative to the record at hand.  This approach uses a join and aggregation to get the result:

```
select t.aId, t.bId, t.cId, tsum.cnt
from t join
     (select aId, bId, cId, count(*) as cnt
      from t
      where createTime <= CURREENT_TIMESTAMP
      group by aId, bId, cId
     ) tsum
     on t.aId = tsum.aId and t.bId = tsum.bId and t.cid = tsum.cId;
```

Note that the expression for the current date/time varies among databases; `CURREENT_TIMESTAMP` is the ANSI standard method.  You might also use `getdate()` (SQL Server), `now()` (MySQL and Postgres), `sysdate` (Oracle), or something else.

The definitions would be additional joins, but you don't even give the names of the tables for that.

Comment: `current_timestamp` would be the ANSI equivalent for `getdate()`

Comment: One thing i forgot, the select needs to bring only the top X records, but the search for duplicates needs to be in all of the table.

Comment: @user1480192 . . . Then depending on your database, you add a `top X` or `limit X` or something similar.  These only apply to the output, not to the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be smth like this

```
SELECT t1.recordid, t1.createdate, t1.aID, t1.bID, t1.cID, isnull(tcount.numberOfRecords10min,0), definitionTable1.aIDdefinition
  FROM t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT aID,bID,cID,count(*) as numberOfRecords10min
      FROM t1
      WHERE createdate >= dateadd(minute, -10, GETDATE())
      GROUP BY aID,bID,cID
    ) tcount on (t1.aID = tcount.aID and t1.bID = tcount.bID and t1.cID = tcount.bID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN definitionTable1 on t1.aID = definitionTable1.aID
```

assuming that the table with the list of records is called `t1` and the table with the definitions for aID is `definitionTable1`

the code is for SQL Server, in case you use another DBMS u will need to replace `dateadd(minute, -10, GETDATE())` for getting the timestamp 10 minutes before now and `isnull(tcount.numberOfRecords10min,0)` for eliminating nulls (replacing with 0)